# accessing properties of companion object from class instance

Tags: scala

What I would like to do is create an instance of a class which has a companion object, and be able to access the static fields in the companion object from the instance of the class.

```
class Person(name: String, age: Integer)
{
    def getAge(): Integer = { age }
    def getName(): String = { name }
}

object Person
{
    def create(name: String, age: Integer)
    {
        new Person(name, age)
    }

    val species = "homoSapiens"
}

object mainMethod
{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    {
        // this is what I want to make work
        val person = Person.create("Sarah", 18)
        println(person.species)
    }
}
```

I understand that with the current setup the species property will not be found when referencing the class instance. My question is, is it possible to manipulate the code above in some way in order to make this work?

Comment: What's wrong with `def species: String = Person.species`?

Comment: What you really wanna do, you can directly use companion to use it's method, like Person.species or Person.create("abc", 18) i would suggest you to use apply method to get a new instance of the class and species as a def.

Comment: @RamanMishra would you be willing to provide a code example which demonstrates this, so that I can better understand your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do that:

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
  def getAge: Integer = {
    age
  }

  def getName: String = {
    name
  }

  def species: String = Person.species
}

object Person {
  def apply(name: String, age: Int): Person = new Person(name, age)

  def species = "homoSapiens"
}

object Solution extends App {
  val person = Person("sarah", 18)

  println(person.species)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! can you also explain why you changed my function name from create to apply?

Comment: How is it different from the first clarification request in the comment section under the question? If your answer looks like *"if you need the method `species`, then define a method `species`"*, then maybe it's because the question didn't make much sense in the first place.

Comment: it's not but OP asked for the code, so i just showed him how we can do that, i think he is new to scala so he couldn't get your comment but your comment was absolutely right. @AndreyTyukin

Answer (score -2):

If you really wanna have it via property, there is one of the weird way:

```
class Person(name: String, age: Integer) {
  def getAge(): Integer = { age }
  def getName(): String = { name }
}

trait PersonProps {
  val species = "homoSapiens"
}

object Person {
  def create(name: String, age: Integer) = {
    new Person(name, age) with PersonProps
  }
}
```

Comment: OP is asking to use the property By companion object not the trait.